# In Python, how to format string while saving in a file

Tags: python, string, format

Is it possible to format strings while saving in a file, similar when printing to a console?

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write('{0:10} {1:10}').format('one', 'two')
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to get the parentheses in the right order... Try splitting it into two lines: created the formatted string, then write that to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. I think that one of your closing parenthesis was not where you meant it to be:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{0:10} {1:10}'.format('one', 'two'))
```